# android emualtor disappears if 3g is turned off

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i press F8 and want to turn 3g off, the virtual device disappears from DDMS. So i had to restart the device for appearing in DDMS. I need to turn off the internet connection to debug functionality of my App.
Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: try to restart adb instead of emulator, it will be faster

Comment: You mean the emulator crashed? If yes, there is not much you can do except to raise a bug report.

Comment: you should read `adb help`. To restart the server, `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`